# Prepared statement returns 0 elements, manual query returns 1

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Basically, it's what the title says. I make a query via mysqli->query and it works. I reword it like this, and it does nothing.

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','test');
if (!$conn) { die('Error1');}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM test_data WHERE type = ?';

$one = 1;

$ps = $conn->prepare($sql);
$ps->bind_param('i', $one);
$ps->execute();

$out = '';

$ps->bind_result($out);
print_r($ps); 
echo out;

$ps->fetch();
print_r($ps);
echo out;
```

The output is the following, repeated twice:

```
mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 1 [field_count] => 7 [errno] => 0 [error] => [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 )
```

Does anyone know what I could use to further *debug* this?

Edit: This is the code that works:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','test');
if (!$conn) { die('Error1');}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM test_data WHERE type = 1';

$ps = $conn->query($sql);

$ps->fetch_assoc();

print_r($ps);
```

Which outputs:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 7 [lengths] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 10 [2] => 3 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 2 ) [num_rows] => 10 [type] => 0 )
```

Comment: What was the original that worked?

Comment: I am a bit confused with your code, you are executing the first query with the first bind_param then you set a new bind_param but does not execute it, your `echo`'s are wrong and with what you have `$ps` should give you the same info both times as there was no changes.

Comment: @Prix Oops. Let me test.

Comment: also you're not reading the result properly if that matters as I am not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: @Prix Could you tell me what's wrong about reading the result? Explain to me like I'm 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you utilize bind_result, you need to know how many columns you're going to have in your result, and you then need to provide a variable for every column in the result.

We can not know what that result set should look like, because you're using SELECT * FROM test_data, but unless test_data only has one column, you are not passing enough variables.

If for example, there are 3 columns in the result set, you need something like:

```
$ps->bind_result($out1, $out2, $out3);
```

From there, you are print_r($ps) which of course is the mysqli object.  I'm not sure what you expect from that, but there's no reason to be trying to dump the object.

If the result set may have more than one row, you need to do a fetch loop:

```
while ($ps->fetch()) {
    echo "$out1, $out2, $out3 <br>";
}
```